# What biological processes occur when you love someone romantically?

Tags: neuroscience, emotion, physical-attraction

How can romantic love be described by scientists?

Comment: It sounds like a big topic. I guess this would be a starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love#Biological_basis

Comment: I don't think love is just a biological process.  Its also a social process: the idea of love itself has many socially defined/described aspects (magazines, movies, friends) thay set expectations for the party's involved.  Of course, the biological aspect (attraction?) is also there.

Comment: There are books on this topic.  From an extremely general physiological point of view - I recall that phenylethylamine is released in your brain for around a year once you fall in love with someone, then after that the relationship is "endorphin based."  I read that somewhere on the internet like 8 years ago so I don't have a citation.

Comment: Can you edit this question and narrow the scope somewhat Miroslav? I think there's a really interesting question here but as it stands an answer could be as long as a book...

Comment: Well, though this book is more about how love is in terms of evolution aspects rather than biological aspect, I would say it is worth reading and you might get some stuffs clear about 'the inside and outside of love'- https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20707972-anatomy-of-love